# Error : Find Largest Number in given numbers

Tags: c

This C program helps to find the largest number in given numbers but it is not working. I have highlighted the line where the problem is.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n,num,i;
    int big;

    printf("Enter the values of n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter %d Numbers :",n);
    scanf("%d",&big);

    for(i=2;i<=n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&num);  //here is the problem..
        //what it is reading as `num` without asking me to entering any thing ?

        if(big<num)
            big=num;
    }

    printf("Largest number is: %d",big);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please explain what the problem is. what do you expect and what actually happens. (note: and don't put the explanation inside the code! marking it, like "here is the problem" is enough)

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your question? To explain the algorithm?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, `
  for(i=2;i<=n;i++){

 scanf("%d",&num); ` what it is reading as NUM. ?

Comment: Would you just want to scanf for number of numbers. Then loop that many times, doing a scanf for a number. Assign big=0 at top. Then after you do scanf in the loop, do that comparison like your doing now.

I am unsure why you do a scanf for your second scanf at the top, or why you start i at = 2

Comment: your `scanf()` (basically) means: "read an integer from the keyboard and store it in `num`". If you want a prompt you have to provide it yourself (with `printf`).

Comment: `scanf` does not scan your input line-wise but token-wise. You might as well input "3 12 23 55" all on one line or put as many blank lines between the numbers as you like. There will be problems if your input isn't a valid integer, though.

Comment: do a temp printf inside the loop and see what the values are.

Comment: I can't figure out what this question is asking. "It's not working" is not helpful. What do you expect it to do, and what is it actually doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the program to ask for input in a user-readable way, you can put

```
printf("Enter number #%d:",i+1);
```

before that line with scanf.

Anyway, the program will do its job just the same if you remove all `printf`'s (and so, print no prompts, only wait for user input). They are only for users' convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Your first scanf command only reads in your first number from stdin.  The one on line 14 reads the rest, one per time around the loop.  Then each one gets compared to variable "big", and replaces it it necessary.